# How do I set up right alignment for horizontal uistackviews embedded within a vertical stackview?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I have a vertical stack view comprised of labels and horizontal button stackviews that looks like this:

```
Label 1 Text Here

SB SB SB SB SB  LargeB

Label 2 Text Here

SB SB SB  LargeB

Label 3 Text Here

SB SB SB  LargeB
```

I want to left align the labels and right align the button stackviews so it looks like this:

```
Label 1 Text Here

    SB SB SB SB SB  LargeB

Label 2 Text Here

          SB SB SB  LargeB

Label 3 Text Here

          SB SB SB  LargeB
```

I have realized I can align the horizontal button stackviews with the trailing edge of the superview but this force thes contents of the stackview to stretch out and occupy the full horizontal space.  I have added leading margins to address this, but it seems very indirect and likely to introduce issues across device sizes.  Is there a way to right align specific contents within a vertical stackview, or a better way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your Vertical Stack View properties:

[image]

Set each Horizontal Stack View properties:

[image]

Make sure **ALL** buttons have `Content Hugging Priority -> Vertical and Horizontal` set to **Required**, and `Content Compression Resistance Priority -> Vertical` set to **Required**:

[image]

Use a clear-background `UIView` as the first arranged subview for any horizontal stack view that does not have the full number of buttons. In this screen-cap, I've set the backgrounds to Teal so you can see where they are:

[image]